# PHP local path to filesystem root

Tags: php, include

I have no idea what I have done. I have a php file "create_account.php" that has

```
<?php include("includes/accounts.php"); ?>
```

In the same folder as "create_account.php", there is a folder "includes", and inside "includes" there is a file "accounts.php". When I try to open "create_account.php" I get a no such file or directory error.

After about an hour of screwing around, I the "includes" folder to the root of my filesystem, and it started working. Why would "includes/accounts.php" open "/includes/accounts.php"

EDIT: Not enough rep to answer my own question so I'll put it here

Ok well this is rather stupid... Turns out my IDE "Coda 2" decided when I click preview ***IT*** should be the one executing the PHP code, not Apache.

/facedesk

Comment: What is your cwd and what your include_path ini directive?

Comment: What is "cwd", also the error I get says the include_path is ".:"

Comment: change your include_path to `.` (The `:` is too much.)

Comment: Used set_include_path to set the include path to ".", still accesses the root filesystem. :3

Comment: Fixed (see original post)

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
<?php include("./includes/accounts.php"); ?>
```

So you could explicitely state you want to open the file in the same directory.

Another idea: Are the file system properties OK? Is the php cgi / webserver allowed to read the file `accounts.php`?

Comment: "./includes/accounts.php" also fails

Comment: As for file system properites, I have no idea how to check if they are  OK or not.

Comment: I thought of the file permissions set by chmod: http://www.macinstruct.com/node/415?ModPagespeed=noscript Have you tried `755` for `accounts.php`?

Comment: Just changed it to 755 (I don't know what it was before), still same result

Comment: Fixed (see original post)